# How to bind table into columns

Tags: r

I have the following table `delete`:

```
  complete    creditcheck     disclosure    getduedates        package        payment        probing serviceability 
         1              2              3              3              2              2              1              1
```

How do I add these columns, as they appear, to my data frame `data_frame`?

Assume that `data_frame` has the same number of rows as `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, as.data.frame.list(delete))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

#   A  B  C
#1  1  4  7
#2  2  5  8
#3  3  6  9
#4 10 10 10
```

If you need to `cbind` the 'delete' with the existing columns

```
bind_cols(df2, as.data.frame.list(delete))
#  V1 V2 V3  A  B  C
#1  1  2  3 10 10 10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data_frame(A=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9)
b <- factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10))
delete <- table(b)
df2 <- data_frame(V1= 1, V2=2, V3=3)
```